# Is $ \iint\frac{f(x)}{g(y)h(z)} dy\,dz$ equal to $f(x) \iint\frac{1}{g(y)h(z)} dy\,dz $?

Tags: integration

Are these two integrals equal?

$$
\iint\frac{f(x)}{g(y)h(z)} dy\,dz = f(x) \iint\frac{1}{g(y)h(z)} dy \,dz
$$

ADDED (Can't put links inside a comment)

Thank you for your prompt reply. Can you please tell me why Wolframalpha is giving me two different answers, one with constants and one without?

1. [integration with function f(t) inside](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B%CE%B2*%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C2%5D*t%2BSqrt%5B%CE%BB%5D*A%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29r%2B%CE%B2*B%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29%CE%B2*%CE%B8%2B%CE%BB*D%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cr%2C%CE%B8%5D)
2. [integration with function f(t) outside](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C2%5D*t%2BSqrt%5B%CE%BB%5D*A%5C%2841%29%20*Integrate%5BDivide%5B%CE%B2%2C%5C%2840%29r%2B%CE%B2*B%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29%CE%B2*%CE%B8%2B%CE%BB*D%5C%2841%29%5D%2Cr%2C%CE%B8%5D)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You may take out the f(x) from the integrand (assuming x is independent of both y and z).

Comment: Yes, even if the limits of integration depend on $x$.

Comment: To answer your added question, the answers are the same; if you scroll to the bottom of the page for when you take f(t) outside, you'll see the 'indefinite integral' solution, which matches the other solution.

Comment: Oh! My bad! Thank you :-)

Comment: To answer your new question, I believe the answers are equivalent but appear different due to the integration constants

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you need to do the integral just with respect to $y$ and $z$. You can look at $f(x)$ as a "constant" in a certe sense.